# How to concatenate these two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

This is a simple operation I am having trouble accomplishing with numpy:

I have two numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([12, 13, 14, 15])
arr2 = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400])
```

I would like four distinct numpy arrays:

```
a1 = np.array([12, 13, 14, 15, 100])
a2 = np.array([12, 13, 14, 15, 200])
a3 = np.array([12, 13, 14, 15, 300])
a4 = np.array([12, 13, 14, 15, 400])
```

What's the most "numpythonic" way to accomplish this?

I could repeat the first array using `numpy.tile`, e.g.

```
repeats = np.tile(arr1, len(arr2))
```

But that's not optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like four distinct numpy arrays:

Are you sure you don't want one array, `np.array([a1, a2, a3, a4])`?

> But that's not optimal.

If optimality is your concern, preallocating results in the fewest copies:

```
N = len(arr1)
M = len(arr2)
result = np.zeros((M, N + 1)
result[:,:N] = arr1
result[:,N] = arr2
```

If you really want to be able to write this kind of thing as an expression, you could define:

```
def build_arr(into, parts):
    for sl, val in parts.items():
        into[sl] = val
    return into

result = build_arr(np.zeros(M, N + 1), {
    np.s_[:,:N]: arr1,
    np.s_[:,N]:  arr2
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and a generator expression:

```
a1, a2, a3, a4 = (np.hstack((arr1, v)) for v in arr2)
```

If you have a variable number of elements in `arr2` then you could store the resulting arrays in a list rather than unpacking them to variable names:

```
arrs = [np.hstack((arr1, v)) for v in arr2]
```

[Dynamically creating variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5036700/1461210) is almost always a bad idea. If you want a variable number of *named* arrays then I suggest you store them in a dict or some other named Python structure. You could use a dict comprehension:

```
named_arrs = {'a%i' % (i + 1): np.hstack((arr1, v)) for i, v in enumerate(arr2)}
```

Comment: `a1, a2, a3, a4 ` What if I don't know a priori the number of arrays which should be generated? One would have to use the length of `arr2`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: Do you really want to create a dynamic number of variable names? That's a _really_ bad idea

Comment: *"I would like four distinct numpy arrays"*. You could easily collect the subarrays in a list if you don't want to unpack them to separate variable names, e.g. `arrs = [np.hstack((arr1, v)) for v in arr2]`.

Comment: @ali_m "I would like four distinct numpy arrays"---yeah, I'm sorry---it's annoying when OPs do this. I should have given the above as an example first.

Comment: So which one do you want? Four separate arrays or one array with four rows?

Comment: @ali_m four separate array, whereby "four" is whatever the length of `arr2` (e.g. if it was `np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600])`, there would be 6 arrays)

Answer (score 1):

I rather like the use of `tile`:

```
In [1684]: np.tile(arr1,[arr2.shape[0],1])
Out[1684]: 
array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
In [1685]: np.concatenate((np.tile(arr1,[arr2.shape[0],1]),arr2[:,None]),axis=1)
Out[1685]: 
array([[ 12,  13,  14,  15, 100],
       [ 12,  13,  14,  15, 200],
       [ 12,  13,  14,  15, 300],
       [ 12,  13,  14,  15, 400]])
```

Such a 2d array is handy in itself. But it can be split into arrays:

```
In [1686]: np.split(_,arr2.shape[0])
Out[1686]: 
[array([[ 12,  13,  14,  15, 100]]),
 array([[ 12,  13,  14,  15, 200]]),
 array([[ 12,  13,  14,  15, 300]]),
 array([[ 12,  13,  14,  15, 400]])]
```

And if you really need separate names for those arrays, unpack the list:

```
In [1687]: a1,a2,a3,a4=_
In [1688]: a1
Out[1688]: array([[ 12,  13,  14,  15, 100]])
```